# Journey Builder shows 0% delivery but also shows number of people opened and clicked on the an email send

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I sent an email on August 25 using Journey Builder and the report showed the number of people opening and clicking on the email but 0% delivery rate. Data view and Email Studio showed the same result and I already made sure that I included pixel tracking in the email. I've checked all accounts and it seems to only affect this account which is on stack 8.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: This could be a bug, I've experienced similar. I would reach out to support.

Comment: Today when I checked again, everything is back to normal. This seemed like a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a temporary glitch on SFMC side

Answer (score 0):

It just takes time to show up in the UI sometimes! IIRC there is no SLA on the tracking. I've had better luck with the Email Studio tracking for Journey sends being faster:
Email Studio > Tracking > Sends > Journey Builder Sends folder > *Journey Name* > *Version #*